# How do I login using the asyncio client for Binance?

Tags: python

I'm trying out the asyncio feature from https://github.com/sammchardy/python-binance/tree/feature/asyncio

In the example, we can see that we log into Binance using our API key and secret with:

```
client = Client(api_key, api_secret)
```

With the second example below it for Asyncio, this hasn't been specified. How would I login through the AsyncClient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Author does *not* recommend using it in production -- the author of the repo very clearly states it is a test branch. However, looking at the code for `python-binance/client.py` you will notice [here](https://github.com/sammchardy/python-binance/blob/feature/asyncio/binance/client.py#L2085-L2094) the following:

```py
class AsyncClient(BaseClient):

    @classmethod
    async def create(cls, api_key='', api_secret='', requests_params=None):

        self = cls(api_key, api_secret, requests_params)

        await self.ping()

        return self
```

Seems like

```py
client = await AsyncClient.create(api_key, api_secret)
```

should work fine.

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm. Just wanted to try out the branch. It hasn't been updated since September last year. I'm hoping he continues production.

Comment: I'm interested in this branch because I have a websocket that streams constant data and I have a bunch of calculations underneath to generate trading signals + make trades. I'm looking for ways to have the latter part operate while the websocket streams.

Comment: You might find [`ccxt`](https://github.com/ccxt/ccxt) useful, though no support for websockets via Binance (except on `ccxt pro`, from my understanding).